# Primefaces selectBooleanCheckbox with binding

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i am trying to make composite component(multiply use on each view) which allows me to show some inputs by checkbox value. One input is depended on checkbox value. I dont want to bind it to bean cause this value is not saved to database or so. I though that i ll save it in view scope holder.

I ve added in face config holder for bindings

```
<managed-bean>
    <description>Holder of all component bindings.</description>
    <managed-bean-name>components</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

composite component:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{components[cc.attrs.bindingId]}">
    <p:ajax update="panel"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:panelGroup id="panel">
    <p:inputText rendered="#{components[cc.attrs.bindingId].value}" value="#{cc.attrs.beanPropertyOnTrue}">
    <p:inputText rendered="#{not components[cc.attrs.bindingId].value}" value="#{cc.attrs.beanPropertyOnFalse}">
</h:panelGroup>
```

It works fine, I can use this component multiply on one view, but the problem is when i am using commandButton to send form to server, checkboxes are changing to unchecked....

```
<p:commandButton value="show decision dialog" 
                 actionListener="#{testBean.action}"
                 update="@form"
                 oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed){ dialog.show() }"/>
```

Comment: You mean here? <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope> with that it still dont work

Comment: i didnt should set anything in value attribute? after update checkbox is always unchecked

Comment: on view i got few occurs of this component and i set there just:
bindingId="optionalForMen#{cc.id}"
bindingId="optionalForWomen#{cc.id}" etc. should i delete this attr and use #{components[cc.id].value} ??

Comment: still not works. After update of form I print value of {components[bindingId].value} and it seems to be empty "". Checkboxes are changing to unchecked visual, and it display only unchecked input(input for value checked is hiding).

Comment: PM 4.0 jsf 2.1 on jboss

Comment: jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar